# How to call id of data which is inserted into database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ado.net

T an entity.I use singleton pattern for database context.

```
   private DbSet<T> _objectSet;
    public Repository()
    {
        _objectSet = db.Set<T>();
    }
    public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
    {
        return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault(query);
    }
    public int Insert(T obj)
    {
        _objectSet.Add(obj);
        return Save();
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Insert is successful but inserted object has returned as null. How can i solve this problem? Thanks for helping.

```
    public BasicResult CreateTask(MTask task)
    {
        BasicResult result = new BasicResult();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        task.ModifiedOn = now;
        task.CreateOn = now;
        task.IsCompleted = false;
        int res=repoTask.Insert(task);
        if (res > 0)
        {
            result.Status = true;
            result.Message = "Successfully added.";
            MTask inserted=repoTask.Find(x => x.Description == task.Description && x.CreateOn == task.CreateOn);
            result.Id = inserted.Id;
            return result;
        }
        result.Status = false;
        result.Message = "An unexpected error occurred.";
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: And how can we guess what is inside `repoTask.Insert` and `repoTask.Find` methods?

Comment: I have no problems inserting but find method returns null.

Comment: And what is `_objectSet` and how/when is it populated?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside `Find`, and evaluate the whole content of `_objectSet`, do you see the newly inserted item?

Comment: After `SaveChanges`, `task.Id` should already contain the assigned value.

Comment: Problem is solved with the way you told. Thanks.

Comment: *"I use singleton pattern for database context"* - do you mean you registered your db context as a singleton? This is a terrible idea; don't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public int Insert(T obj)
    {
        _objectSet.Add(obj);
         Save();
         return obj;
    }
    public int Save()
    {
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and you can easily get the id from the object returned by your Repository.Insert(T obj)

```
var savedObject = repoObject.Insert(task);
var id = savedObject.Id;
```

making ur insert method call SaveChanges will take away the option to do transnational insertion/update , you should read more about unit of work